# How to play a raw OPUS stream?

Tags: audio, ogg

I have a piece of software that outputs raw OPUS streams, without any container. I do know that it is mono and 16kib/s. However, opusdec or other tools I have tried to not want to read it, since it is not in an ogg container or similar.

How can I play / convert such a file?

Comment: Do you have a sample?